# Stuck at swing bridge in Hunrath

Tags: obduction

I have done everything in Hunrath, I have been up to the tower and junkyard areas, and I know that I need to get to Maray or Kaptor.

But I accidentally swung the bridge right round to the extreme left so now I cannot cross the bridge to get to swap seed machines.

Is there any way to swing this bridge back or any other way to get to the other worlds so I can continue the game.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Obduction Gamepedia](https://obduction.gamepedia.com/Kaptar_swing_bridge_puzzle) it's possible (I don't play this game so I might just be giving you info you already know but i think this solves your problem).

The site states that:

> When you reach go to the center go down the ladder and turn the crank fully and you will see that the radar will turn, then make the move to the right or left! To do this, go to the center and tighten in the right direction and the bridge moves to the edge and then lower the latch! Once you've done that you have to do it and turn the other way twice to go to the other side of Kaptar!